# How to write Japanese with ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, japanese

Would you mind explaining to me why the following ConTeXt code does not work and how I can fix it?

```
\mainlanguage[ja]

\definefontfamily[mainface][serif][Heisei Mincho Std][tf=file:HeiseiMinStd-W3.otf, bf=file:HeiseiMinStd-W7.otf]

\setupbodyfont[mainface, serif, 11pt]
\definebodyfontenvironment[default][a=1.09, b=1.18, x=0.9, xx=0.89]

\starttext

渡辺 謙（わたなべ けん、1959年10月21日 - ）は、日本の俳優。本名同じ。

\stoptext
```

After typesetting (TeXShop: ConTeXt (LuaTeX)), the result is a blank page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does ConTeXt find the font files? You can run the following example to test it: `\starttext \doifelsefontpresent{HeiseiMinStd-W3}{YES}{NO} \stoptext`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Metafox . The command "\doifelsefontpresent{HeiseiMinStd-W3}{YES}{NO}" does absolutely nothing. I tried to replace the japanese text with a french text and it still does not work. The page I get is blank.

Comment: You should have used the command in a document without any custom fonts.

Comment: Now it works. The answer is YES.

Comment: @ Metafox . Sorry I didn't tag you on my last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your fonts with a short typescript for them.

```
\starttypescript [serif] [heisei]
    \setups[font:fallback:serif]
    \definefontsynonym [Serif]     [file:HeiseiMinStd-W3.otf]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [file:HeiseiMinStd-W7.otf]
\stoptypescript

\definetypeface [mainface] [rm] [serif] [heisei] [default] [features=default]
\definetypeface [mainface] [mm] [math]  [modern] [default]

\setupbodyfont[mainface,11pt]

\mainlanguage[ja]

\setscript[nihongo]

\starttext

渡辺 謙（わたなべ けん、1959年10月21日 - ）は、日本の俳優。本名同じ。

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Metafox. It works great now.Could you explain what went wrong in my code? I do not fully understand the difference between the \definefontfamily mechanism and the typescript/typeface mechanism. Thanks in advance.